# onclick not working in listview: switch case error

Tags: android, onclick, listviewitem

The problem is in the `switch` statement as I couldn't get the `ListView` items position to display anything. I then have to use a webview to open a html document using the `ListView`. What is wrong with my code?

```
public class Main extends Activity {

private ListView mListView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    ArrayList<MyData> myDataList = new ArrayList<MyData>();
    MyData one = new MyData("Text one", 1);
    MyData two = new MyData("Text two", 2);
    MyData three = new MyData("Text three", 3);
    MyData four = new MyData("Text four", 4);
    MyData five = new MyData("Text five", 5);
    MyData six = new MyData("Text six", 6);
    MyData seven = new MyData("Text seven", 7);
    MyData eight = new MyData("Text eight", 8);
    myDataList.add(one);
    myDataList.add(two);
    myDataList.add(three);
    myDataList.add(four);
    myDataList.add(five);
    myDataList.add(six);
    myDataList.add(seven);
    myDataList.add(eight);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_);

    mListView.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.row, myDataList));

}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyData> implements
OnClickListener {

    public ArrayList<MyData> items;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<MyData> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        MyData myData = items.get(position);
        if (myData != null) {
            TextView textViewTwo = (TextView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.text_view_two);
            if (textViewTwo != null) {
                textViewTwo.setText(myData.getText());
                // put the id to identify the item clicked
                textViewTwo.setTag(myData.getId());
                textViewTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        }
        return v;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 

        this switch statement is the real problem 

         switch (v.getId()) {
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "text 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    break;


                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "default", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    break;
            }



    }

}

private class MyData {
    private String text;
    private int id;

    public MyData(String text, int id) {
        this.text = text;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please post your error log.

Comment: 05-12 13:57:05.015: W/Trace(880): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0     "its just the logcat msg... my app works but doesn't display the toast onClick !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this very good question.... all others are answers wrong...anyone give right answer for this question otherwise dont give crap like ths

```
switch(postion)
{
case 1:
...
Case 2:
.....
}
```

Comment: wow ! its working ... thanks for your contribution man ...@mohan .... are you working for a German company !

Comment: This is does not answer the question. Why is it accepted and upvoted?

Answer (score 1):

in ListView use **OnItemClickListener** to implement List Item Click:

```
YourList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) 
{
   //Your Code Here
}
});
```

Comment: He is asking about one of `textview` of his `listview`.

Comment: @Gunaseelan : Ty for your comment,My answer is just related to : i couldn't get the list view items position to display a toast

Comment: thanks @Arash ! but this onItemClickListener cannot b implemented ... it doesn't even show up in javadoc (ctrl+space)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
switch (v.getId()) {
       case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "text 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    break;


                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "default", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    break;
            }
```

This to

```
switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.text_view_two:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "text 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    break;                    
            }
```

like this. Because `v.getId()` always return id of your `View`. So you have to check it with your id of `View` only.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: A little explanation to go along with this code would have gotten an upvote from me.

Comment: thanks @Gunaseelan ... this code didn't work ..." i have 6 switch cases "

Comment: in case you can use 6 `case` each with separate id. Surely it will work. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should set id for your view first:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)
        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

        v.setId(items.get(position).getId()); //<- this
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks ! I tried this addon to my existing code .. but didn't work ... can u suggest any other code